# Animate Scroll View to show same content with different values iOS Swift

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to animate the scroll view to show the same views but with different values based on the selection on the segmented control.I need left to right & right to left slide animation to show different values on the same UI. I dont want to create duplicate views.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Wanted to avoid creating multiple tableviews just for animation sake.
Here is how I solved it :

**Basic idea** : Take a screenshot of tableview and display it on the root view. Then, do a slide animation of tableview from Left to Right (or Right to left depending on the switching of segment control)

*Code when swiped to right*

```
func switchToLeft() {
    let newIndex = currentIndex - 1
    if newIndex > 0 {
        let sS = showScreenShot()
        self.tableView.animateFromLeft(0.5){
            sS.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        //update data and RELOAD your tableview here
    }
}

func showScreenShot() -> UIView{
    let image = getScreenShot()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let blankView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    blankView.addSubview(imageView)
    self.tableView.superview?.addSubview(blankView)
    self.tableView.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
    return blankView
}

func getScreenShot() -> UIImage?{
    let viewToRender = self.tableView
    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToRender.bounds.size)

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // need to translate the context down to the current visible portion of the tableview

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -contentOffset.y-tableHeaderHt)

    viewToRender.layer.renderInContext(ctx)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

*Leaving off code for `animateFromLeft` as an exercise!*